# detect click on element with a child inside

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$('.parent').on('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target.matches('.inside')) {
    console.log('inside');
  } else {
    console.log('title');
  }
});
```

```css
.parent {
  background: lightgreen;
}

.inside {
  background: silver;
}

.title {
  background: gold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='inside'>
    <div class='title'>lorem</div>
  </div>
  <br>
</div>
```

Click on `inside` and you'll get `title` in console.

How to get `inside` regardles a `title` is inside or not?

Comment: is it just me that finds the question unclear?

Comment: @treyBake, need to get `inside` in console if `inside` is clicked, that's all

Comment: @qadenza can you not just target the element with the 'inside' class? e.g. ```$('.inside').on('click', function() { console.log('inside') })``` or am I missing something?

Comment: @JamieBradley, no, in reality my markup is more complex and I need to target `parent`

Comment: `$('.parent > .inside').on('click', function(e){console.log('inside');});` how about this?

Comment: @Durga, I need to target parent because another elements are sometimes missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check if the `target` has a *parent* `.inside` :-

```js
$('.parent').on('click', function(e) {
  if ($(e.target).parents('.inside').length) {
    console.log('inside');
  } else {
    console.log('title');
  }
});
```

```css
.parent {
  background: lightgreen;
}

.inside {
  background: silver;
}

.title {
  background: gold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='inside'>
    <div class='title'>lorem</div>
  </div>
  <br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay take a look at this and see if it works for you?

https://codepen.io/jamie-endeavour/pen/GPjzRq?editors=1011

```
$('.parent').on('click', function(e) {
  var $target = $(e.target);

  if ($target.hasClass('inside') || $target.parent().hasClass('inside')) {
    console.log('inside');    
  } else {
    console.log('not inside');
  }
});
```

I am checking if the user has clicked on the element with the 'inside' class or if the child element belongs to the 'inside' element.

Hope this helps?

Answer (score 0):

Please note that HTML works in layer so if title is going to be inside "inside", you can just target title for click as inside is always "inside" it.

```js
$('.title').on('click', function(e){
 console.log('inside');
});
```

```css
.parent{
background:lightgreen;
}
.inside{
background:silver;
}
.title{
background:gold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='parent'>
<div class='inside'>
<div class='title'>lorem</div>
</div>
<br>
</div>
```

Comment: I need to target `parent` because another elements are sometimes missing